# Удалил всё что было в gitignore. Как восстановить?

Tags: git

У меня в untracked были файлы, который я хотел сбросить, git reset --haerd HEAD не помогал.

Я погуглил. Наткнулся на ответ на SO - [ВОТ ОТВЕТ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200622/how-to-remove-untracked-files-in-git)

написал замечательную команду - git clean -fdx

все что было в гитигноре удалилось! что делать?

Comment: А вы ответ внимательно читали? Там же написано: `-x - remove ignored files too ( don't use this if you don't want to remove ignored files)`

Comment: а как восстановить ?((

Comment: Посмотрите про `git reflog`

Comment: @Nilsan а разве эти файлы гит как-то сохраняет ?

Comment: Никак. Вернее точно также как любой другой удалённый файл, каким-нибудь инструментом для восстановления удалённых файлов. Гит тут ни при чём